# Image upload MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

My react and node application are on different directories, what i want is to upload image in react send it to the backend through axios request and in node receive that image then rename it into current date and time and finally save it in the current backend directory, if the image is saved successfully then return it to the frontend through node backend and display the image on react.

This is what i have tried to achieve my desired goal.

**Form**

```
<div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlFile1">
                  Example file input
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  className="form-control-file"
                  id="exampleFormControlFile1"
                  onChange={this.fileSelectedhandler}
                />
              <button onClick = {this.onSubmit}> Upload</button> 
 </div>
```

**Arrow Function call when click on submit**

```
onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.state.file);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

     const { fileName, filePath, file } = res.data;

      //setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });

      //setMessage('File Uploaded');
      console.log(fileName, filePath, file);
      this.setState({ imagesHello : res.data});
      
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
      
        console.log("There was a problem with the server");
      }
    }
  };
```

**Backend api**

```
//route for uploading image(optional)
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(200).json({ msg: "No File Uploaded" });
  }

  const file = req.files.file;
  let ts = Date.now();

  let date_ob = new Date(ts);
  let date = date_ob.getDate();
  let month = date_ob.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = date_ob.getFullYear();

  // prints date & time in YYYY-MM-DD format
  const newFile = `${year} + "-" + ${month} + "-" + ${date}`;

  file.mv(`${__dirname}/uploads/${file.name}`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json({
        fileName: file.name,
        filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}`,
        file: req.files.file,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The problem with this code is that the file is saved into the backend directory but not returning to the frontend now what i want to do is to send back this saved image to the react frondend and display it in response to the above `/upload` post request.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the specific problem or issue you are facing?  Please update the question to reflect this.

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the message on the frontend that the data is get saved successfully....
you can return some response from the backend and during fetch while getting response without error you can toast the message (Materializecss Toast)

```
 M.toast({html:"uploaded", classes:"#6a1b9a purple"})
```